# How to make a rigid body and soft body object collide

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, soft-body

I’m trying to make a ball which has the rigid body fall and crush a cube with the soft body.

I’ve already tried giving the cube a rigid body along with the soft body but the ball just freezes after it makes contact with the cube and the cube does nothing as well.

Comment: Well, the simple answer to this is: rigid body physics and soft body physics do not interact with each other. The soft bodies only react to collision objects, the rigid bodies only to other rigid bodies.

Comment: Yes but you can give a Collisions physic to a Rigid Body object, that said it seems hard to get something satisfying

Comment: i would try to do it with two softbodies + collision and try to tweak the settings for the one as "hard and rigid" as possible and the other more soft